# How to use serde serialize_with inside a custom Serializer for a struct

Tags: rust, serde

I have the following code and it is working as expected.

```
use serde::{ Serialize, Serializer };

// Define your struct with optional fields.
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: i32,
    field2: Option<String>,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "custom_serialize_field3")]
    field3: Option<i32>,
    field4: i32,
    field5: Option<String>,
    custom_field: Option<String>,
}

// Define a custom serialization function for field3.
fn custom_serialize_field3<S>(field3: &Option<i32>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where S: Serializer
{
    // Implement custom serialization logic for field3 here
    match field3 {
        Some(value) => serializer.serialize_i32(*value),
        None => serializer.serialize_i32(0),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = MyStruct {
        field1: 42,
        field2: Some("Hello".to_string()),
        field3: None,
        field4: 99,
        field5: Some("World".to_string()),
        custom_field: Some("CustomValue".to_string()), // Set a custom value here
    };

    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&data).expect("Serialization failed");

    println!("{}", serialized);

    let data2 = MyStruct {
        field1: 42,
        field2: Some("Hello".to_string()),
        field3: Some(1000),
        field4: 99,
        field5: Some("World".to_string()),
        custom_field: Some("CustomValue".to_string()), // Set a custom value here
    };

    let serialized2 = serde_json::to_string(&data2).expect("Serialization failed");

    println!("{}", serialized2);
}
```

[Working Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=daff55f9bb60521276f2ab89f392053a)

Now I have a condition that when `field3` and `field5` both are set, we should not serialise and return an Error.

```
error: cannot find attribute `serde` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:7
  |
7 |     #[serde(serialize_with = "custom_serialize_field3")]
  |       ^^^^^
  |
  = note: `serde` is in scope, but it is a crate, not an attribute
```

For that I am trying to use the custom Serialiser for struct but getting error. I have made the following code and removed `#[derive(Serialize)]` from sstruct:

```
impl Serialize for MyStruct {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> where S: Serializer {
        if self.field3.is_some() && self.field5.is_some() {
            return Err(serde::ser::Error::custom("Both field3 and field5 can't be present"));
        }

        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("MyStruct", 6)?;
        state.serialize_field("field1", &self.field1)?;
        state.serialize_field("field2", &self.field2)?;
        state.serialize_field("field3", &self.field3)?;
        state.serialize_field("field4", &self.field4)?;
        state.serialize_field("field5", &self.field5)?;
        state.serialize_field("custom_field", &self.custom_field)?;
        state.end()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=66f8ccb4d90e945473d87e12adccc937)

Comment: You should just remove `#[serde(serialize_with = "custom_serialize_field3")]` (but also need to handle that in the serializer if you want).

Comment: Yaa, I tried that but the results are not expected. How to use the`custom_serialize_field3` there is something I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Hint: look at how serde expands `#[serde(with)]` and think how to apply it to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to implement the `0` fallback inside of the `Serialize` implementation and remove the `custom_serialize_field3` alltogether:

```rust
impl Serialize for MyStruct {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        if self.field3.is_some() && self.field5.is_some() {
            return Err(serde::ser::Error::custom(
                "Both field3 and field5 can't be present",
            ));
        }

        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("MyStruct", 6)?;
        state.serialize_field("field1", &self.field1)?;
        state.serialize_field("field2", &self.field2)?;
        state.serialize_field("field3", &self.field3.unwrap_or(0))?;
        state.serialize_field("field4", &self.field4)?;
        state.serialize_field("field5", &self.field5)?;
        state.serialize_field("custom_field", &self.custom_field)?;
        state.end()
    }
}
```

But if you **must** use the `custom_seralize_field3` function (as suggested by your question title), you can do the same as what `serde` does internally:

```rust
impl Serialize for MyStruct {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        if self.field3.is_some() && self.field5.is_some() {
            return Err(serde::ser::Error::custom(
                "Both field3 and field5 can't be present",
            ));
        }

        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("MyStruct", 6)?;
        state.serialize_field("field1", &self.field1)?;
        state.serialize_field("field2", &self.field2)?;
        state.serialize_field("field3", {
            #[derive(Serialize)]
            #[serde(transparent)]
            struct Wrapper<'a>(
                #[serde(serialize_with = "custom_serialize_field3")] &'a Option<i32>,
            );
            &Wrapper(&self.field3)
        })?;
        state.serialize_field("field4", &self.field4)?;
        state.serialize_field("field5", &self.field5)?;
        state.serialize_field("custom_field", &self.custom_field)?;
        state.end()
    }
}
```

Comment: The suggested `Wrapper` is not equivalent to `custom_serialize_field3`. Maybe with the addition of `serde(transparent)`.

Comment: @jonasbb Are you sure? It serializes identically ...

Comment: @jonasbb Either way, I added it as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mix serialization and validation. You can have a `BuildMyStruct` that takes care of serialization and implement a `build` function on `BuildMyStruct` that takes care of validation.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    field1: i32,
    field2: Option<String>,
    field3: Option<i32>,
    field4: i32,
    field5: Option<String>,
    custom_field: Option<String>,
}

// Define your struct with optional fields.
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct BuildMyStruct {
    field1: i32,
    field2: Option<String>,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "custom_serialize_field3")]
    field3: Option<i32>,
    field4: i32,
    field5: Option<String>,
    custom_field: Option<String>,
}

impl BuildMyStruct {
    pub fn build(self) -> Result<MyStruct, ()> {
        if self.field3.is_some() & self.field5.is_some() {
            Err(())
        } else {
            let Self {
                field1,
                field2,
                field3,
                field4,
                field5,
                custom_field,
            };
            Ok(MyStruct {
                field1,
                field2,
                field3,
                field4,
                field5,
                custom_field,
            })
        }
    }
}
```